# How does nodejs load native addons?

Tags: c++, node.js, shared-libraries

The way I understand it native addons for node are just shared objects or dynamically linked libraries on the operating system. Normally though, dynamically linked libraries are linked at load time. But in node you can require() modules dynamically. So how does this work? Is it more like dynamic loading with dlopen and the function pointers?

Comment: Yes, libs can be loaded at runtime with functions like dlopen etc. on Linux, LoadLibrary etc. on Windows ... Are you doubting it? Why?

Comment: I don't know. Seemed like a brittle solution since node would have to know interface to extract the symbols. But I guess it's not since the addon's external API is really node's "exports" js object. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed native addons for node are dynamically loaded. Taken from [this](http://www.missioncriticallabs.com/blog/dependencies-between-c-addons-in-node) post:

> C/C++ addons are just dynamic libraries, and Node loads those libraries with a function in libuv called uv_dlopen. That provides a uniform interface for loading dynamic libraries on both Windows and Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 0):

nodejs supports addons that are written in other languages (such as C/C++).  As such, those other languages can use all OS facilities to dynamically load other DLLs, either system DLLs or their own DLLs.

If you want to read more about the nodejs add-on process, you can see here: [Nodejs Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).

Built in library support (such as the fs module) has the same ability.

Comment: From your link - "Addons are dynamically linked shared objects." This is where my confusion started. I guess the distinction between dynamically "linked" and "loaded" is too fine.